# is there a bootstrap dropdown that works like a combobox?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I want a textbox where the user can type any value or click a dropdown arrow and select from a list of values.  An  element with an associated  list of values would work well.   Would like it styled like a bootstrap dropdown. And supported on all browsers.

Is there anything in bootstrap that provides this functionality?

Comment: what is off topic about asking if bootstrap has a combobox or if it has better support for datalist? I search and did not find anything. But maybe bootstrap has a different way of doing a combobox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe there is anything built-in to bootstrap that is exactly what you're looking for; however, I Googled 'bootstrap combobox' and found this plugin that looks really nice: https://github.com/danielfarrell/bootstrap-combobox

If you don't want to use a plugin, your best bet is probably just a `<select>` element plus an alternate `<input />` field if the user doesn't find what they are looking for in the `<select>`.